# netbeans and the jUDDI annotations

Tags: java, web-services, netbeans, uddi

I'm trying to get the jUDDI annotations working in netbeans 7.0. I've included juddi-client-3.0.4.jar and uddi-ws-3.0.4.jar in my project libs and put a uddi.xml in the config folder. It seems the juddi classes aren't in the classpath though, cos when I try to deploy I get the error below. How do I setup netbeans to handle this? Thanks.

```
I:\java\src\svn\PeopleWS\trunk\build\classes\PeopleWSServiceBean.class: warning: Cannot find annotation method 'businessKey()' in type     'org.apache.juddi.v3.annotations.UDDIService': class file for org.apache.juddi.v3.annotations.UDDIService not found
I:\java\src\svn\PeopleWS\trunk\build\classes\PeopleWSServiceBean.class: warning: Cannot find annotation method 'serviceKey()' in type 'org.apache.juddi.v3.annotations.UDDIService'
I:\java\src\svn\PeopleWS\trunk\build\classes\PeopleWSServiceBean.class: warning: Cannot find annotation method 'description()' in type 'org.apache.juddi.v3.annotations.UDDIService'
I:\java\src\svn\PeopleWS\trunk\build\classes\PeopleWSServiceBean.class: warning: Cannot find annotation method 'bindingKey()' in type 'org.apache.juddi.v3.annotations.UDDIServiceBinding': class file for org.apache.juddi.v3.annotations.UDDIServiceBinding not found
I:\java\src\svn\PeopleWS\trunk\build\classes\PeopleWSServiceBean.class: warning: Cannot find annotation method 'description()' in type 'org.apache.juddi.v3.annotations.UDDIServiceBinding'
I:\java\src\svn\PeopleWS\trunk\build\classes\PeopleWSServiceBean.class: warning: Cannot find annotation method 'accessPointType()' in type 'org.apache.juddi.v3.annotations.UDDIServiceBinding'
I:\java\src\svn\PeopleWS\trunk\build\classes\uk\ac\susx\peoplews\session\PeopleWSServiceBean.class: warning: Cannot find annotation method 'accessPoint()' in type 'org.apache.juddi.v3.annotations.UDDIServiceBinding'
error: Could not create declaration for annotation type org.apache.juddi.v3.annotations.UDDIService
error: Could not create declaration for annotation type org.apache.juddi.v3.annotations.UDDIServiceBinding
2 errors
7 warnings
error: compilation failed, errors should have been reported
Exception occured in J2EEC Phase
com.sun.enterprise.deployment.backend.IASDeploymentException: WSGEN FAILED
at com.sun.enterprise.webservice.WsUtil.genWSInfo(WsUtil.java:2256)
at     com.sun.enterprise.deployment.backend.ModuleDeployer.loadDescriptors(ModuleDeployer.java:427)
at   com.sun.enterprise.deployment.backend.EjbModuleDeployer.deploy(EjbModuleDeployer.java:141)
at   com.sun.enterprise.deployment.backend.ModuleDeployer.doRequestFinish(ModuleDeployer.java:182)
at com.sun.enterprise.deployment.phasing.J2EECPhase.runPhase(J2EECPhase.java:208)
at  com.sun.enterprise.deployment.phasing.DeploymentPhase.executePhase(DeploymentPhase.java:108)
at  com.sun.enterprise.deployment.phasing.PEDeploymentService.executePhases(PEDeploymentService.java:966)
at     com.sun.enterprise.deployment.phasing.PEDeploymentService.deploy(PEDeploymentService.java:283)
at com.sun.enterprise.deployment.phasing.PEDeploymentService.deploy(PEDeploymentService.java:835)
at com.sun.enterprise.management.deploy.DeployThread.deploy(DeployThread.java:187)
at com.sun.enterprise.management.deploy.DeployThread.run(DeployThread.java:225)
```

Comment: I should have made it clear that I'm using glassfish 2.1, have added the juddi libs to glassfish, and my juddi setup is working ok -- I can register services etc using soapUI and a simple client I wrote.

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar error once and solved it changing the version attribute of the web-app element in the web.xml file from 2.5 to 2.3.
Just with that change my deployment worked OK.
I hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Most likely, there's a conflicting version of the juddi-client.jar somewhere in the classpath. Often web servers will include a version in their distribution.